# Python httplib2: HTTPS login fails

Tags: python, http, https, httplib2

I am trying to use [httplib2](https://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) to log in to a web page. I am able to log in to the page by simply opening the following URL in a Chrome incognito window:

```
https://domain.com/auth?name=USERNAME&pw=PASSWORD
```

I tried the following code to emulate this login with httplib2:

```
from httplib2 import Http
h = Http(disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True)
resp, content = h.request('https://domain.com/auth?name=USERNAME&pw=PASSWORD')
```

Unfortunately, this request does not lead to a successful login.

I tried changing the request headers to match those provided by Chrome:

```
headers = {
    'Host': 'domain.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8'
}
resp, content = h.request('https://domain.com/auth?name=USERNAME&pw=PASSWORD', 'GET', headers=headers)
```

This changes the response slightly, but still does not lead to a successful login.

I tried inspecting the actual network traffic with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) but since it's HTTPS and thus encrypted, I can't see the actual traffic.

Does anybody know what the difference in requests between Chrome and httplib2 could be? Maybe httplib2 changes some of my headers?

Comment: are you redirected after succesful login? are some cookies set on the way?

Comment: just use `requests`, it will save you a lot of sleepless nights.

Comment: ``requests`` is a life saver!!! Works like a charm. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Games Brainiac's comment, I ended up simply using [Python Requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead of `httplib2`. The following `requests` code works out of the box:

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get('https://domain.com/auth?name=USERNAME&pw=PASSWORD')
```

Further requests with the same username/password can simply be performed on the `Session` object:

```
...
next_response = session.get('https://domain.com/someOtherPage')
```